# How to use ignorecase when using contains(text(), "string") in XPath expressions in CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, xpath, casperjs

```
if (casper.exists(x('//p[@class="classname" and (contains(text(), "this is my string."))]'))){
    //code
}
```

I want to be able to match `"this is my string."` as well as `"thiS is My striNg."`.
I couldn't find any functions to do this. It is okay to change the text on the screen to lowercase or uppercase and then match but it shouldn't change all the text rather just the string that I want to search for. But I couldn't find how to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that Casper JS only supports XPath 1.0. In that case you can't use the `lower-case()` function, but you can use `translate()` to replace a collection of characters with their lower-case representation. You need to include all the characters that can have upper and lowercase representations (including accented characters, for example), in order.

For example: the expression:

```
translate('street', 'tse', 'sto')
```

replaces each `t` for an `s`, each `s` for a `t` and each `e` for an `o`. It results in:

```
tsroos
```

So you can use

```
translate(text(),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```

to translate all upper-case ASCII characters in your string to lower-case. Applying this you your example, you can use:

```
//p[@class="classname" 
  and (contains(translate(text(),"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
                                 "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"), 
                                 "this is my string."))]
```

Comment: Thank you for response but it is not working. As can be seen from your answer, the syntax of `translate()` is `translate("base string","charaters to replace", "characters that replace the previous ones")`. But in the solution that you gave, the syntax is `translate(text(),"all uppercase","all lowercase"),"mystring")`. Maybe I should put "mystring" next to `text()` and bracket it? Even so, it will as per my understanding replace "mystring" to lowercase. Even then if the webpage has "mySTRING", it will not match.Am I right? In that case how should I modify the code?

Comment: The code is correct. It should work, unless your context is incorrect or the string you are matching doesn't match even in lowercase (should the period really be there?). The function is `translate(text(),"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")`. This will replace upper for lowercase in the string received as text. The *result* will be used in the `contains()`: `contains( result , "this is my string.")` so it will test if your string occurs in the *result* string.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. Now I know how the thing works and it seems it should work. I will look at my code again and try to make it work. Thank you again, the code does seem correct from your explanation. I'll accept the answer as soon as I get it to work.

Comment: The problem is that I had an uppercase character in the string that I was providing. Works now. Thanks.